# What is being filtered?

Tags: qgis, postgis

I have a Postgres/postgis table of polygons. When added to QGIS the total feature Count is 64671 in layer tree and attribute table. But the attribute table also says Filtered: 43573. I have not applied any filter.

What is total Count (what is 64671 and what is 43573)? What filter is applied?

[image]

Does not seem like it is the total single part Count either:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

QGIS queries and fetches indexed sources based on the canvas position/extent, plus tolerance;

- the *Features* count is the total count of entries in the table
- the *Filtered* count is the amount of features that has actually been loaded from
  DB

Try it; the filter count changes when you pan/zoom.